# Strange Casting behavior in Spring REST Template

Tags: spring, rest, casting, resttemplate

I am using Spring to develop REST web service. The first code below is a method of my web service that returns a list of users. And the second code is my Spring REST Template client getting the response from that web service method.

Web Service method to fetch list of users:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/allusers", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers() {

    List<UserDetails> users = userServices.getAllUsers();
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setExpires(600);
    HttpEntity<List<UserDetails>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(users, header);
    HttpStatus httpStatus;
    if(users != null){
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
    } else {
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpEntity, httpStatus);
}
```

REST Client

```
@RequestMapping("/list_all_users")
public ModelAndView goAllUsers() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("allusersdisplay");
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/SpringRestAddrs/services/allusers";
    RestTemplate rTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    *List<String> users = (List)rTemplate.getForObject(url, HttpEntity.class).getBody();*
    mv.addObject("users", users);
    return mv;
}
```

I expect a `ClassCastException` on the line surrounded by asterisks(*) as the body of the `HttpEntity` object contains a list of objects of type `UserDetails` whereas the `List` defined on the left side expects a list of objects of type `String`. What is really happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You're only casting it to a generic List in this example. Casting to `List<String>` should give you the "desired" error.

```
List<String> users = (List<String>)rTemplate.getForObject(url, HttpEntity.class).getBody();
```

Comment: This will give me an error at compile time. But the code shown in my post should throw a runtime error when casting `List<UserDetails>` to `List<String>`. isn't it?

Comment: Again, you're casting it as a generic List in this case, which does not try to match the type in this line. You will get a ClassCastException if you try to access an object in your List "users".

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this behavior because you're casting to List.

Whe the JVM executes

```
List<String> users = (List)rTemplate.getForObject(url, HttpEntity.class).getBody();
```

The JVM is only pointing the users variable to that space of memory. If you want to get **ClassCastException** you have to use any of the values of the List. For example:

```
System.out.println(users.get(0));
```